# Collapsing factors and mutating rows with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Given:

```
x <- data.frame(Day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                var1 = c(5,4,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4),
                var2 = c(3,6,2,3,4,5,7,8,1,2),
                var3 = c(1,2,3,4,6,2,4,7,8,4),
                var4 = c(1,3,7,5,3,7,2,3,1,2))
```

The day variable at the moment is numeric but corresponds to 1= Monday, 5= Friday, 6=Monday, 10=Friday. I'd like to collapse all the  respective days together and average their values out by day:

```
z <- data.frame(Day = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"),
                var1 = c(5,2.5,2,3,4),
                var2 = c(4,6.5,5,2,3),
                var3 = c(1.5,3,5,6,5),
                var4 = c(4,2.5,5,3,2.5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `modular` `%%`:

```
days = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")
x %>% group_by(Day = days[(Day - 1) %% 5 + 1]) %>% summarise_all(mean)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
#        Day  var1  var2  var3  var4
#      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    Friday   4.0   3.0   5.0   2.5
#2    Monday   5.0   4.0   1.5   4.0
#3  Thursday   3.0   2.0   6.0   3.0
#4   Tuesday   2.5   6.5   3.0   2.5
#5 Wednesday   2.0   5.0   5.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is ordered, create the grouping variable by replicating the day and then with `summarise_at` get the `mean` of the 'var' columns

```
library(dplyr)
 v1 <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
            "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday")
x %>%
   group_by(Day = factor(rep(v1, 2), levels = v1))  %>%
   summarise_at(vars(matches('var')), mean)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#     Day  var1  var2  var3  var4
#       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    Monday   5.0   4.0   1.5   4.0
# 2   Tuesday   2.5   6.5   3.0   2.5
# 3 Wednesday   2.0   5.0   5.0   5.0
# 4  Thursday   3.0   2.0   6.0   3.0
# 5    Friday   4.0   3.0   5.0   2.5
```

---

If the data is not ordered, then create a key/value dataset, join with the original dataset, after grouping by the 'Day', get the `mean` as above

```
x1 <- data.frame(Day = 1:10, DayC = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
        "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday"), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)

x %>%
  left_join(., x1) %>% 
  group_by(Day = DayC) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(matches('var')), mean) %>%
  arrange(factor(Day, levels = v1))
```